# Remove "All Members" tab in Buddypress search results

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

Is it possible to remove the "All Members" tab and list of members on the Members page and search results in buddypress? Currently there are two tabs, "All Members" and "My Friends". I do not want to display a list of all my buddypress members so I want to remove this completely hopefully without having to change the core files which I know isn't recommended.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the tab instead of hiding it, create a [template overload](https://codex.buddypress.org/themes/theme-compatibility-1-7/a-quick-look-at-1-7-theme-compatibi%20lity/#how-is-this-useful)  of this file:

buddypress\bp-templates\bp-legacy\buddypress\members\index.php

And simply delete the list element that creates the All Members tab.

To change what is displayed below those tabs, create a template overload of this file:

buddypress\bp-templates\bp-legacy\buddypress\members\members-loop.php

And adjust as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You may make both tabs invisble using CSS which is less painful (but it can be undone changing the css property using dev tools).

Try searching both tabs ID's or classes, then modify your buddypress css template file with:

```
.TabClassName {
   display:none!important;
}
```

or

```
#TabId {
   display:none!important;
}
```

The !important is to overwrite any other tab visibility modifier. More info [where](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_display_visibility.asp).